# Can SonarQube connect Azure SQL Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sonarqube, jruby, azure-sql-database

My SonarQube is running on VM instance of Microsoft Azure. Now the SonarQube's database is MySQL, and I'm trying to change MySQL to Azure SQL Database, but SonarQube couldn't connect Azure SQL Database by some erroes which occured at ActiveRecord component. I know SonarQube doesn't support Azure SQL Database officially and support SQL Server below, nevertheless Azure SQL Database is compatible with SQL Server, so It's may possible to connect Azure SQL Database.
Please tell me how to connect Azure SQL Database if anybody knows.

[SonarQube's Support Database](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-SupportedPlatforms)

sonar.properties:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar@<server>
sonar.jdbc.password=<password>
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>.database.windows.net:1433/<databasename>;ssl=require
```

error trace:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no connection available
    from arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517:in `set_native_database_types'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61:in `initialize'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    from jar:file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440:in `initialize'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74:in `automatic_setup'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:239:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'
    from file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in `load_environment'
    from file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79:in `load_environment'

    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ConnectionNotEstablished) no connection available
    at arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.set_native_database_types(arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517)
    at RUBY.initialize(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61)
    at RUBY.initialize(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31)
    at RUBY.jdbc_connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227)
    at RUBY.new_connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223)
    at RUBY.checkout_new_connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245)
    at RUBY.checkout(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519)
    at RUBY.checkout(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184)
    at RUBY.mon_synchronize(jar:file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191)
    at RUBY.checkout(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183)
    at RUBY.connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98)
    at RUBY.retrieve_connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326)
    at RUBY.retrieve_connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123)
    at RUBY.connection(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115)
    at RUBY.initialize(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440)
    at RUBY.up(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401)
    at RUBY.migrate(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383)
    at RUBY.upgrade_and_start(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62)
    at RUBY.automatic_setup(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74)
    at RUBY.(root)(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:239)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79)
```

Thanks

Comment: it seems that AR can not connect using the specified *database.yml* parameters ... you did not share those here yet the should be relevant in terms of configuring a MS-SQL connection

Comment: My connection configuration is following.
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
And I removed these entry from sonar.properties, but sonarqube have not connect to azure sqldb yet.

Comment: that is likely not what you fed AR while connecting, right?!

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what I need to share because I'm beginner in ruby. sonarqube's ruby is running on jruby and connecting to Azure sqldb via jTDS driver, so I thikn configuration is jdbc.url below.
'sonar.jdbc.ur=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>.database.windows.net:1433/<databasename>;ssl=require'
Thanks

Comment: OK NP - I'me a beginner in SonarQube ... so I'm not sure how it works but ActiveRecord/Rails is usually using *config/database.yml* or the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` variable to configure connections ... anything you know about those being used on SonarQube ?

Comment: SonarQube use database.yml which placed in ～/WEB-INF/conf directory. database.yml's content is following.

'base: &base
  adapter: jdbc
  dialect: <%= ::Java::OrgSonarServerUi::JRubyFacade.getInstance().getDatabase().getDialect().getActiveRecordDialectCode() %>
  pool: <%= ::Java::OrgSonarServerUi::JRubyFacade.getInstance().getConfigurationValue('sonar.jdbc.maxActive') || 10 %>

development:
  <<: *base

production:
  <<: *base

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000'

Thanks

Comment: could you maybe instead include that formatted as is in the answer itself ? thanks

Comment: also your activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem (1.1.3) is fairly old while e.g. jruby-rack (1.1.13.2) is quite "new" ... any chance for a potential upgrade or is it a locked-down production environment ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can change some purpose files by overwriting easily, but I think it may not work fine. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, I just discovered, after spending 6 pretty frustrating hours on this issue. Here are the issues I encountered and the solutions I came up with for each:

1. Couldn't connect to the Azure SQL Server database -- connection would just time out. The solution was to add ";ssl=require" to the connection URL and -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false (see [Connecting to Azure SQL DB via JTDS on an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846978/connecting-to-azure-sql-db-via-jtds-on-an-android-device)) to the server's java parameters (in conf/wrapper.conf). Here's what my database configuration looks like:

   ```
   sonar.jdbc.username=<username>@SERVER
   sonar.jdbc.password=<password>
   sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433/DATABASE;ssl=require;SelectMethod=Cursor
   ```

   I also upgraded the jTDS driver in extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql from 1.2.8 to 1.3.1, but that might not be necessary.
2. SonarQube creates some tables without clustered indexes, which Azure SQL Server doesn't support (see [Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492175/tables-without-a-clustered-index-are-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-server)). To solve that issue, I needed to install SonarQube locally using a local SQL Server Express instance. After doing that I ran the following DDL to convert the problematic tables to use clustered indexes:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx_schema_migrations ON dbo.schema_migrations(version);
   CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx_groups_users ON dbo.groups_users(user_id,group_id);
   ```

   Finally, now that the database is Azure-compatible, inside SSMS I right-clicked on the database, selected Tasks/Deploy Database to SQL Azure, and deployed it to my Azure server.
3. SonarQube's database upgrader doesn't support SQL Server 2014 (you get a "Deprecated feature 'DROP INDEX with two-part name' is not supported in this version of SQL Server" error while it's upgrading from 4.3 to 4.4). I had to do a fresh install to get around that issue, though it's probably possible to either figure out the necessary upgrade DML/DDL yourself or upgrade SonarQube's ActiveRecord JDBC MSSQL adapter (hoping they'll do that in their next version).

Simple, huh? :p

Comment: I'm sorry I gave you spending time a lot. This is great solution you introduced. I couldn't come up with the way using SQL Server for making compatible DML/DDL to SQL Azure. It's not simple for me :-o

Answer (score 2):

For me it works only when database name is separated in properties and without jtds e.g.

```
sonar.jdbc.username=<username>@SERVER
sonar.jdbc.password=<password>
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433;database=DATABASE;ssl=require;SelectMethod=Cursor
```

Sonar Qube version 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL is not the same as a local MS SQL Server install.

Differences are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx

Also the documentation of Sonarqube only shows up to MS SQL Server 2008. Azure will be based on a system similar (not identical) to MS SQL Server 2014 at the time of this writing. (They are always updating their system).

Comment: Thank you for your answer soon. I've known difference between mssql and azure sqldb, and I've known jTDS which is used by SonarQube can connect to Azure SQL Database, so I think SonarQube can connect to Azure SQL Database. [jTDS to SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickhodge/archive/2010/01/25/jdbc-to-sql-azure.aspx) Regards.