# Sonar-Postgres Docker Issue

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to use sonar and postgres containers. Below is my docker-compose file

```
sonarqube:
  image: sonar-master
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  links:
   - db:db
  environment:
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
db:
  image: postgres:9.5.3
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
```

When I try to hit sonar url, I am getting the below stacktrace in browser

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no connection available
from arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517:in `set_native_database_types'
  from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61:in `initialize'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `initialize'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
from jar:file:/opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440:in `initialize'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74:in `automatic_setup'
from /opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:239:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'
from file:/opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in `(root)'
from file:/opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in `load_environment'
from file:/opt/sonarqube-4.3.2/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79:in `load_environment'
```

It appears that sonar is not able to connect to postgres. And I am not able to find any details in docker logs. Please help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: What hostname are you using to connect to postgresql?

Comment: I believe you need a `POSTGRES_DB=sonar` as well in your DB service

Comment: have you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202819/can-sonarqube-connect-azure-sql-database

Comment: I am using hostname as "db" which I have given in "links". Tried with "POSTGRES_DB=sonar" in DB service. But still the same error

Comment: SonarQube 4.3.2 is almost 4 years old, latest LTS is 6.7, You should try first to upgrade as I have no idea if version 4.3.2 is compatible with Postgres SQL 9.5

Comment: thank you. I found out the issue. Sonar is referring to properties in sonar.properties, though I am passing environment variables. I have used variable substitutions in property file and it worked. Julien, Our java code quality rules are not compatible with latest sonar version. So we are forced to use 4.3 for now.